# c++ Variable was not delclared in this scope in expansion of macro

Tags: c++, declaration, adafruit

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I am trying to add support for the esp32 to the HX8357D 3.5" TFT display from Adafruit ([link](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-3-5-color-320x480-tft-touchscreen-breakout/overview)). I made a fork of the library from Adafruit ([link](https://github.com/DvDriel/TFTLCD-Library/tree/esp32)) that handles the 8-bit parallel interface and added an esp32 branch. I figured out most of the components needed, but I'm having trouble to get the code to compile. Could someone help me with getting it to work?

I made an Arduino sketch with the code that has to be implemented into the library:

```
//Not used in this sketch, but these are the 5 control pins for the TFT display
#define LCD_CS 27
#define LCD_CD 26
#define LCD_WR 25
#define LCD_RD 14
#define LCD_RESET 13

//8 data pins (random, but made sure they are all ardressable with one register)
#define DATA_PIN0 3
#define DATA_PIN1 18
#define DATA_PIN2 5
#define DATA_PIN3 17
#define DATA_PIN4 16
#define DATA_PIN5 4
#define DATA_PIN6 2
#define DATA_PIN7 15

#define DELAY     200

gpio_config_t io_conf;

//Some random data to write to the gpio pins, creates a pattern to the LED's that I connected
uint32_t data[] {
  0b00000000000000001000000000001000,
  0b00000000000001000000000000000100,
  0b00000000000000000000000000110000,
  0b00000000000000110000000000000000,
  0b00000000000000000000000000000000,
  0b00000000000000110000000000000000,
  0b00000000000000000000000000110000,
  0b00000000000001000000000000000100,
  0b00000000000000001000000000001000
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  setReadDir();
  print32Bits(GPIO.in);
  setWriteDir();
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    GPIO.out_w1tc = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    GPIO.out_w1ts = data[i];
    delay(DELAY);
  }
}

//Set 8 data pins to OUTPUT
void setWriteDir() {
  io_conf.intr_type = GPIO_INTR_DISABLE;
  io_conf.mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT;
  io_conf.pull_down_en = GPIO_PULLDOWN_DISABLE;
  io_conf.pull_up_en = GPIO_PULLUP_DISABLE;
  io_conf.pin_bit_mask =  ((1ULL << DATA_PIN0 ) | (1ULL << DATA_PIN1) | (1ULL << DATA_PIN2) | (1ULL << DATA_PIN3) | (1ULL << DATA_PIN4) | (1ULL << DATA_PIN5) | (1ULL << DATA_PIN6) | (1ULL << DATA_PIN7)); // of course, do like this all the pins
  gpio_config(&io_conf);
}

//Set 8 data pins to INPUT
void setReadDir() {
  io_conf.intr_type = GPIO_INTR_DISABLE;
  io_conf.mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  io_conf.pull_down_en = GPIO_PULLDOWN_DISABLE;
  io_conf.pull_up_en = GPIO_PULLUP_DISABLE;
  io_conf.pin_bit_mask =  ((1ULL << LCD_CS ) | (1ULL << LCD_CD) | (1ULL << LCD_WR) | (1ULL << LCD_RD) | (1ULL << LCD_RESET)); // of course, do like this all the pins
  gpio_config(&io_conf);
}

//Function to print 32 bit interger to Serial, just for convenience
void print32Bits(uint32_t myByte) {
  for (uint32_t mask = 0x80000000; mask; mask >>= 1) {
    if (mask  & myByte) {
      Serial.print('1');
    } else {
      Serial.print('0');
    }
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

I added the necessary code to `ADAFRUIT_TFTLCD.h`, `ADAFRUIT_TFTLCD.cpp` and `pin_magic.h`

The functions in `pin_magic.h` (`write8inlin` and `read8inlin`) are not completely done yet. I tried to compile the code to test whether the stuff I had done so far would compile correctly, but I am getting a lot of `....was not declared in this scope` errors.

In `pin_magic.h` I have:

```
#define RD_ACTIVE  GPIO.out_w1tc |=  rdPinset
#define RD_IDLE    GPIO.out_w1ts |=  rdPinSet
#define WR_ACTIVE  GPIO.out_w1tc |=  wrPinset
#define WR_IDLE    GPIO.out_w1ts |=  wrPinSet
#define CD_COMMAND GPIO.out_w1tc |=  cdPinset
#define CD_DATA    GPIO.out_w1ts |=  cdPinSet
#define CS_ACTIVE  GPIO.out_w1tc |=  csPinset
#define CS_IDLE    GPIO.out_w1ts |=  csPinSet
```

The first part of the error that I get:

```
D:\ProgramData\Arduino\libraries\TFTLCD-Library\pin_magic.h:389:42: error: 'csPinset' was not declared in this scope

     #define CS_ACTIVE  GPIO.out_w1tc |=  csPinset

                                          ^

D:\ProgramData\Arduino\libraries\TFTLCD-Library\Adafruit_TFTLCD.cpp:268:5: note: in expansion of macro 'CS_ACTIVE'

     CS_ACTIVE;

     ^
```

If someone with more experience in C/C++ could have a look at it I would be super grateful.

Comment: please post the exact error messages and a [mcve]

Comment: `Serial`, `setReadDir`, `print32Bits`, and many others are not defined anywhere. Maybe you forgot some `#include`s (the headers you mentioned) at the beginning?

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness of the question, I did my best to outline the error as best as possible. I added the exact lines of code that are wrong according to the compiler. @CristiFati The example code is only an Arduino sketch, the functions are not part of the library but merely to test how to control the esp32's gpio pins.

Comment: `csPinSet` != `csPinset` - if this is deliberate, it's a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your code, are you compiling it in your PC? Looks like the compiler is ignoring the declaration of the csPinset etc due to you #ifdef block -

I'm not familiar with AVR environment, but I recommend compiling your code with the correct compiler(eg AVR compliant) in the intended environment. Alternatively, you can also define __ AVR __ at compile time using the -D option:

g++ < file_name.cpp > -D__AVR__

## EDIT

To make sure the variables you need are declared for all environment, you can change the header file to something like this-

```
#ifndef USE_ADAFRUIT_SHIELD_PINOUT
  
    #ifdef AVR
        // "Variable declaration for AVR goes here"

    #elif defined SAM
       //"Variable declaration for SAM goes here"

    /*else block, in case ESP32 is not the correct macro name*/
    #else
      //"General Variables for everything else other than SAM or AVR."
    #endif
  
//in case the ADA SHIELD PINOUT is defined
#else
//"General Variables for when USE_ADAFRUIT_SHIELD_PINOUT is defined."

#endif
```

This should fix the "variable not declared" error. You can explore or ask in https://arduino.stackexchange.com the right way to customise this header for the ESP32 env.

Comment: To compile the code I use the Arduino IDE with the esp32 Arduino core. I am not sure what the name of the compiler is, but it comes with the installment of the esp32 Arduino core and I believe it is the same as the one used with the esp-idf. If I select a AVR board, like the Arduino in the IDE everything compiles fine.

Comment: Ah! So i believe the compilation will work for __AVR__ and __SAM3X8E__ alone.
your source code uses these variables for all the architectures - AVR, ESP32, __SAM3X8E__ etc. But by defining it under #ifdef __AVR__ & __SAM3X8E__ block, you are limiting the variable definition to AVR & SAM arch alone.
Add a general else block,  defining the variables incase the architecture is not __AVR__ or __SAM3X8E__ in Adafruit_TFTLCD.h. That should solve your problem

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do ;). If you look at the files in [link](https://github.com/DvDriel/TFTLCD-Library/tree/esp32) you can see that I added similar `#ifdef` statements for `ESP32`. The problem is that for some reason the compiler gives me errors like in the example: `'csPinset' was not declared in this scope`. I tried to make the **ESP32** part the same as the **AVR** and **SAM3X8E**, but something is going wrong.

Comment: I've edited my answer. This will make sure the variables are declared no matter what! 
If you still get the same error even after making the suggested changes, the order of header file inclusion is the culprit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865785/why-does-the-order-of-my-includes-matter-c